# How to save picture to iPhone photo library?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, camera, uiimage

What do I need to do to save an image my program has generated (possibly from the camera, possibly not) to the system photo library on the iPhone?

Comment: You can check [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41797659/7030209). Great day!

Answer (score 417, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, 
                               id completionTarget, 
                               SEL completionSelector, 
                               void *contextInfo);
```

You only need **completionTarget**, **completionSelector** and **contextInfo** if you want to be notified when the `UIImage` is done saving, otherwise you can pass in `nil`.

See the [official documentation for `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum?language=objc).

Comment: Take +1 for the accurate answer

Comment: Hi thanks for your great solution. Here I have one doubt how can we avoid duplicates while saving image in photo library. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to save in better quality, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379274/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-saves-to-wrong-size-and-quality

Comment: Remember to add key 'Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description' to your info.plist file

Comment: You will now need to add 'Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description' as of iOS 11 to save photos the users album.

Comment: how to give a name to the saved images?

Answer (score 63):

**Deprecated in iOS 9.0.**

There`s much more fast then UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum way to do it using iOS 4.0+ AssetsLibrary framework

```
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
    if (error) {
    // TODO: error handling
    } else {
    // TODO: success handling
    }
}];
[library release];
```

Comment: Is there a way to save arbitrary metadata along with the photo?

Comment: I tried saving using `ALAssetsLibrary`, it takes just the same time to save as `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

Comment: And this freezes the camera :( I guess it is not background supported ?

Comment: This one is so much cleaner b/c you can use a block to handle completion.

Comment: I am using this code and i am including this framework #import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h> not the AVFoundation. Shouldn't the answer be edited? @Denis

Comment: Nice but has been deprecated in iOS 9 SDK.

Answer (score 33):

The simplest way is:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myUIImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

For `Swift`, you can refer to [Saving to the iOS photo library using swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/13/5/saving-to-the-ios-photo-library)

Comment: I really like your SO user profile icon. Pretty cool Xcode image.

Comment: Fantasticly simple, and very very easy!

Answer (score 13):

One thing to remember: If you use a callback, make sure that your selector conforms to the following form:

```
- (void) image: (UIImage *) image didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo;
```

Otherwise, you'll crash with an error such as the following:

`[NSInvocation setArgument:atIndex:]: index (2) out of bounds [-1, 1]`

Answer (score 10):

Just pass the images from an array to it like so

```
-(void) saveMePlease {

//Loop through the array here
for (int i=0:i<[arrayOfPhotos count]:i++){
         NSString *file = [arrayOfPhotos objectAtIndex:i];
         NSString *path = [get the path of the image like you would in DOCS FOLDER or whatever];
         NSString *imagePath = [path stringByAppendingString:file];
         UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]autorelease];

         //Now it will do this for each photo in the array
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
        }
}
```

Sorry for typo's kinda just did this on the fly but you get the point

Comment: Using this will miss some of the photos, I've tried it. The correct way to to it is to use call back from completion selector.

Comment: can we save images with the custom name?

Comment: One should never use for loop for this. It leads to the race condition and crashes.

Answer (score 4):

When saving an array of photos, don't use a for loop, do the following

```
-(void)saveToAlbum{
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startSavingToAlbum) withObject:nil];
}
-(void)startSavingToAlbum{
   currentSavingIndex = 0;
   UIImage* img = arrayOfPhoto[currentSavingIndex];//get your image
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}
- (void)image: (UIImage *) image didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo{ //can also handle error message as well
   currentSavingIndex ++;
   if (currentSavingIndex >= arrayOfPhoto.count) {
       return; //notify the user it's done.
   }
   else
   {
       UIImage* img = arrayOfPhoto[currentSavingIndex];
       UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In **Swift**:

```
    // Save it to the camera roll / saved photo album
    // UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.myUIImageView.image, nil, nil, nil) or 
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.myUIImageView.image, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)

    func image(image: UIImage!, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError!, contextInfo: AnyObject!) {
            if (error != nil) {
                // Something wrong happened.
            } else {
                // Everything is alright.
            }
    }
```

Comment: yes...nice..but after save image i want to load image from gallery... how to do that

Answer (score 4):

**Below function would work. You can copy from here and paste there...**

```
-(void)savePhotoToAlbum:(UIImage*)imageToSave {

    CGImageRef imageRef = imageToSave.CGImage;
    NSDictionary *metadata = [NSDictionary new]; // you can add
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:imageRef metadata:metadata completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL,NSError *error){
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"Image save eror");
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4

```
func writeImage(image: UIImage) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.finishWriteImage), nil)
}

@objc private func finishWriteImage(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Something wrong happened.
        print("error occurred: \(String(describing: error))")
    } else {
        // Everything is alright.
        print("saved success!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my last answer will do it..

for each image you want to save, add it to a NSMutableArray

```
    //in the .h file put:

NSMutableArray *myPhotoArray;


///then in the .m

- (void) viewDidLoad {

 myPhotoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];



}

//However Your getting images

- (void) someOtherMethod { 

 UIImage *someImage = [your prefered method of using this];
[myPhotoArray addObject:someImage];

}

-(void) saveMePlease {

//Loop through the array here
for (int i=0:i<[myPhotoArray count]:i++){
         NSString *file = [myPhotoArray objectAtIndex:i];
         NSString *path = [get the path of the image like you would in DOCS FOLDER or whatever];
         NSString *imagePath = [path stringByAppendingString:file];
         UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]autorelease];

         //Now it will do this for each photo in the array
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
        }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, it always missed some of the photos. Have a look at my answer. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18220664/927208)

Answer (score 1):

```
homeDirectoryPath = NSHomeDirectory();
unexpandedPath = [homeDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:@"/Pictures/"];

folderPath = [NSString pathWithComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithString:[unexpandedPath stringByExpandingTildeInPath]], nil]];

unexpandedImagePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingString:@"/image.png"];

imagePath = [NSString pathWithComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithString:[unexpandedImagePath stringByExpandingTildeInPath]], nil]];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:folderPath isDirectory:NULL]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath attributes:nil];
}
```

Comment: This answer is not right because it doesn't save the image to the system Photo Library, but to the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

I created a UIImageView category for this, based on some of the answers above.

Header File:

```
@interface UIImageView (SaveImage) <UIActionSheetDelegate>
- (void)addHoldToSave;
@end
```

Implementation

```
@implementation UIImageView (SaveImage)
- (void)addHoldToSave{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}

-  (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        UIActionSheet* _attachmentMenuSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                          delegate:self
                                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Save Image", nil];
        [_attachmentMenuSheet showInView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame]];
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        //Do nothing
    }
}
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if  (buttonIndex == 0) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil,nil, nil);
    }
}


@end
```

Now simply call this function on your imageview:

```
[self.imageView addHoldToSave];
```

Optionally you can alter the minimumPressDuration parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 2.2**

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image: UIImage, _ completionTarget: AnyObject?, _ completionSelector: Selector, _ contextInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
```

If you do not want to be notified when the image is done saving then you may pass nil in the **completionTarget**, **completionSelector** and **contextInfo** parameters.

Example:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.imageSaved(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

func imageSaved(image: UIImage!, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: AnyObject?) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // Something wrong happened.
        } else {
            // Everything is alright.
        }
    }
```

The important thing to note here is that your method that observes the image saving should have these 3 parameters else you will run into NSInvocation errors.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img.image, nil, nil, nil);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5.0

I used this code to copy images to photo albums my application had created;
When I want to copy images files I call "startSavingPhotoAlbume()" function.
First I get UIImage from App folder then save it to photo albums.
Because it is irrelevant I dont show how to read image from App folder.

```
var saveToPhotoAlbumCounter = 0



func startSavingPhotoAlbume(){
    saveToPhotoAlbumCounter = 0
    saveToPhotoAlbume()
}

func saveToPhotoAlbume(){  
    let image = loadImageFile(fileName: imagefileList[saveToPhotoAlbumCounter], folderName: folderName)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if (error != nil) {
        print("ptoto albume savin error for \(imageFileList[saveToPhotoAlbumCounter])")
    } else {
        
        if saveToPhotoAlbumCounter < imageFileList.count - 1 {
            saveToPhotoAlbumCounter += 1
            saveToPhotoAlbume()
        } else {
            print("saveToPhotoAlbume is finished with \(saveToPhotoAlbumCounter) files")
        }
    }
}
```