# Saving custom image (non-JPEG) to iPhone Photos directory

Tags: iphone

I'm wondering if it's possible to save a non-JPEG file (e.g. PNG) to the iPhone Photos album.  I'm trying to do this in order to save a lossless image.  Currently, I'm saving to the application bundle's document folder, but I'd like to be able to save to the iPhone Photos album so the images may be viewed later (without explicitly copying them out of the bundle).  The function `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` will not work because it writes a JPEG file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can use a workaround, I've found it [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489250/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-save-as-png-with-transparency) on SO.

Comment: This post discusses the method I'm using currently, that is, saving directly to the application bundle rather than the user's Photo album.  Though the author does comment that my desired task is not possible, so I guess that's my answer.