# Saving UIImage as PNG to photo album on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage, png, ios4, nsdocumentdirectory

I am merging some png files to a uiimage and I followed this thread ( [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum save as PNG with transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489250/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-save-as-png-with-transparency) )

and tried to save the result as a png file by replacing this code with my image: [self composeImageWithWidth:100 andHeight:100)..

When I test this using simulator, I go to the folder in application support and find the png there. However when I test this on a real device, I cannot find the png file in my photo album.

What could be going wrong?
Perhaps the paths of photo album?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: try that: UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(yourImageHere, nil, nil, nil);

Comment: it doesn't save as PNG, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);
```

You only need completionTarget, completionSelector and contextInfo if you want to be notified when the image is done saving, otherwise you can pass in nil.

[More info here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum)

Comment: I was already using this but it doesn't save as a png file.. That's why I used the other example. But then the place is not photo album of the iphone. This is what I am trying to solve :]

Comment: This only saves as a JPG not as a PNG