# Writing text to transparent UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uikit, core-graphics

I want to write a text string on a fully transparent image (alpha 0 everywhere) but it doesn't work. The background of the image turns to be white if alpha of background image is 0. Here are the approaches I tried:

```
extension UIColor {
  func image(_ size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) -> UIImage {
      return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { rendererContext in
          self.setFill()
          rendererContext.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
      }
  }
}


 func textToImage(drawText text: String, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
    let textColor = UIColor.blue
    let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 40)!

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
        ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

    let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

And then:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    let inImage = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0).image(CGSize(width: 800, height: 800))
     //Even tried inImage = UIImage(named: "Transparent") where Transparent.png is fully transparent image! // 

    let image = textToImage(drawText: "Test String", inImage: inImage, atPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

No matter what I do, the background is white.

Comment: For me your code work just fine, maybe you are saving to jpeg instead of png, which support alpha channel?

Comment: Ok it turns out UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum doesn't saves images with full alpha to photo library because by default it is in jpeg. Tried on UIImageView and works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting to png

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let inImage = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0).image(CGSize(width: 800, height: 800))
     //Even tried inImage = UIImage(named: "Transparent") where Transparent.png is fully transparent image! //

    let image = textToImage(drawText: "Test String", inImage: inImage, atPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

    self.image.image = image


    if let pngdata = image.pngData() {
        if let newImage = UIImage(data: pngdata) {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I've tested Your code in playgroung, and it works as it should

So The reason is Apple Gallery representations of alpha channels. Looks like it's not supported

Comment: Ok so followed this code to save png to Photo Library and it works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489250/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-save-as-png-with-transparency