# Saving images inside iPhone application without using database or server side saving technique

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I am developing an application which requires saving images in the "saved folder" of iPhone Photo album after performing some animations on ImageViews. Is it possible to save the incomplete images temporarily in the iphone application without using database or server side saving technique, so that user can use it for future use and only completely changed ones should get saved in Photo Album? If yes then it would be a great help to get any code or suggestion.

Thanks in advance :) !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, images can be converted to NSData objects, which can then be written to a standard file. Check out UIImagePNGRepresentation() and -[NSData writeToFile:atomically:].

Answer (score 0):

You can then save to the standard native Photo album application using the technique described here (from a `UIImage` instance):

[How to save picture to iPhone photo library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library/179066#179066)