# Is it possible for my app to install default image set as an album on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm creating an app that will use UIImagePicker to let users pull custom images from their Camera Roll. However, I also would like to include a set of my own images with the app, so that users have the option of using those. I'm wondering if on the first install of my app there's a way to put those default images in their own album inside Photos? I figure this way I would avoid having to create in-app photo gallery. Other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to display the default apps with a UIImagePicker? Or did you find some other way?

Comment: @Jenny No, I do not believe there is a way for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said other suggestions are welcome I will post this as an answer rather than a comment.

First I would ask yourself,

1. What is the reasoning for the default images?

   Users have the ability to delete images from their photo library, if you are relying on these default images to be there, this is not a good solution.
2. Will this feature upset users?

   As a user myself, I would be pretty annoyed if an app forced its own pictures into my album, unfortunately the iPhone doesn't allow good organizing of pictures on the device itself, making something like this even more annoying.
3. Will this void Apple's EULA/TOS?

   I can very easily see your app being rejected by the reviewers for doing something like this. It's very intrusive so to speak and if it is possible to pull off without user acknowledgement I think it walks on the line of the "app sandbox" rule. Meaning your app needs to keep its data in it's own area.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I'm a new developer and still getting familiar with the guidelines. I have since opted to include default images within my app to avoid some of the issues that you mention. It all makes sense. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start here: [How to save picture to iphone photo library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library)