# How can I save the image to the iPhone photo album? 

Tags: iphone, imageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save picture to iPhone photo library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library)

I want to know about iPhone photo album and also how to save the particular image to the iPhone photo album with the button click event.

In my view having only one image view in that imageview one image is there. I want save that particular image to the iphone photo album programmatically how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answers to [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library). See the reference for [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum).

Comment: UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(appDelegate.PreviewimageView.image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);    while i'm giving like above the photo had stored in photo album  but app get terminated ...what should i do to solve this issue..

Comment: @Mano Ammu: Post the exact error message from the debug console. Do you actually have a `image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:` method on `self` ?