# How to save edited image?

Tags: ios4, uiimageview, save, uiimagepickercontroller

I have UIImagePicker to select the image. After selecting the image I am editing it and now I want to save that image.

Can anyone please tell me how can I save the image to Photo Album?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this tutorial

http://iosdevelopertips.com/camera/camera-application-to-take-pictures-and-save-images-to-photo-album.html

here is my code to get image if the image is edited then edited image will be taken into account.

if not edited then original image will be taken

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

UIImage *image;

if (picker.editing == YES) {

        image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];  

}
else {
        image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

    //  [picker release];

    //  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: sorry for this stupid question but pls tell me what is info here. M getting error info - undeclared.

Comment: u have to put ur code inside of this method  -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

Comment: just copy above code and paste in ur .m file then inside do what ever u want

Comment: m totally new to iphone development, now the error is : error: 'imagePickerController' undeclared (first use in this function) Is PickerViewController is the name of the Class As mine is RootViewController???

Comment: @interface urViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

Comment: please download the above tutorial project then see step by step and then copy paste like that in urs.then do as u needed by changing some code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *yourImage, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);
```

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library) to this question...And about completionTarget and completionSelector, from documentation...

> The use of the completionTarget, completionSelector, and contextInfo
>   parameters is optional and necessary only if you want to be notified
>   asynchronously when the function finishes writing the image to the
>   user’s Camera Roll or Saved Photos album. If you do not want to be
>   notified, pass nil for these parameters.