# iphone-on the button click image should be stored in photo library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working with many images in my app. and  on the save button I would like to store that perticular image in my photo library. How can I do this? Do you have any idea? If yes then plz provide me the code..

thanx in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save picture to iPhone photo library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helps to save the image to the photo album of the device.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(yourImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to save to the photo library. The most "modern" way of handling this is to make use of the `ALAssetsLibrary`.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = myUIImage.CGImage;
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:imageRef orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)UIImageOrientationUp completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){

    //do whatever you wish at the conclusion of the save.
    }

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below method to save images to album

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageobj, nil, nil, nil);
```