# save image in iPhone photo library with high resolution with retina display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm developing an app in which i have to save images in iPhone photo library. When i'm saving image in iPhoto library in app programmatically i want the image to be saved with high resolution with retina display. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Create an image with retina resolution and save it. What's the question here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save picture to iPhone photo library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its upto your requirement how you are saving the images in the application. If you are resizing the images while saving them then you can try to save a better version as well so it may work in both resolutions. However, the question is very vague. Please do give some more explanation.