# GPUImagePicture with imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput doesn't get UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, gpuimage

I'm using GPUImage for processing a local photo, I'm using this to initialize:

```
localImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:selectedImage];
```

Then I'm adding the filters and I can see it on the screen.

Problem is that I need UIImage to save it but when I call:

```
[localImageSource imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput]
```

I get nothing.

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling that with the **filter** itself apparently solve this problem:

```
[filter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

Credits to brspurri