# Failed to save UIImage in Photo Library in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, phphotolibrary

I am using swift PHPhotoLibrary class to save image in photo library. Below is my code:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges( {
        let assetCreation = PHAssetCreationRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(self.photoView.image!)
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((self.photoView?.image)!,1)
        let option = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
        assetCreation.addResourceWithType(PHAssetResourceType.FullSizePhoto, data: imageData!, options: option)


    },
    completionHandler: {
            success, error in
        if success {
            print("save image success" )
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

But I always got this error message: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)")
This error was printed by the else line: "print(error)"

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: which line gives you the error.

Comment: the line "print(error)"

Comment: This Will help you to save UIImage to photo album [Save UIImage to Photo Album](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library)

Comment: This link does solve my problem but I want to understand more. The code in the link is using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() method to save photo. I wander what the different between this one and PHPhotoLibrary. Why didn't my code not work?

Comment: Just to confirm, the error you get is compile time right?

Comment: yes, it happens on compile time

Comment: Are you using as Target IOS 10? If you do make sure add the following in your info.plst file

You have to add the below permission in Info.plist. Permission in Info.plist

Camera :

Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description   

Value     :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use

Photo :

Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description    

Value     :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use

Copied from :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631256/request-permission-for-camera-and-library-in-ios-10-info-plist