# Saving Screenshot captured from XCUIScreenshot Function

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to use the function screenshot in XCTest to capture a screen, but I am unable to understand how to save this screenshot on to a simulator device or physical device

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiscreenshot

I am trying to Automate UI testing here and will need to capture a lot of screenshots for review.

Comment: The screenshot is saved on the machine running the test and not on the device you're running the test on.

Answer (score 1):

On the object `XCUIScreenshot` you have a property `image` using it you can retrieve and save the screenshot wherever you want.

To save the image you can see this topic : [How to save picture to iPhone photo library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [this](https://github.com/zmeyc/UITestUtils). Download the source and import the needed stuffs into your code.

Its very simple to take screenshots while running UI tests. Just call `saveScreenshot(path)` method to take and save screenshots in desired path.