# How can I save my UIImageView contents to my gallery? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Just started a few days ago and trying to learn. I have an image within my `UIImageView`, how do I save this to my gallery? I have created a button with an `IBAction` on it

Is it related to `.pngData()` ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save picture to iPhone photo library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library)

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func nameOfFunctionToSave(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageTake.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

extension photoPickerController :  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate  {
    func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
         if let error = error {
          // in case we get an error
           let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
           present(alert, animated: true)
         } else {
          // in case of success
           let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Image saved successfully in your library", preferredStyle: .alert)
           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
           present(alert, animated: true)
         }
}
```