# Save image to photo library SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm using SDWebImage to show image from url in swiftUI project

```
var body: some View {
    WebImage(url: URL(string: "https://nokiatech.github.io/heif/content/images/ski_jump_1440x960.heic"))
    .onSuccess { image, data, cacheType in
    }
    .resizable() // Resizable like SwiftUI.Image, you must use this modifier or the view will use the image bitmap size
    .placeholder(Image(systemName: "photo")) // Placeholder Image
    .placeholder {
        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.gray)
    }
    .indicator(.activity) // Activity Indicator
    .transition(.fade(duration: 0.5)) // Fade Transition with duration
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
}
```

I want to save this image on long press,
How can save it to the libaray?

Comment: you can use the factory `[UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum)` inside the `.onSuccess{ ... }` closure.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29133115/14591716)

Comment: I want to save it on long-press gesture

Comment: @KishoreSuthar, then add it into the `.onLongPressGesture { ... }` closure...

Comment: but How I will get the reference of image in longPressGesture

Comment: @KishoreSuthar, what about having maybe an eg. `private var myImage: Image` reference?

Comment: We can't use this

Comment: @KishoreSuthar, sorry for my bluntness but there is no reason of why you could not use standard properties

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236681/discussion-between-kishore-suthar-and-holex).